# Builds filtered by tags

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS2015 on-premise in the Build hub there is an option to filter the builds based on Tags but whatever value I add to this filter the builds list remains unchanged.

Do you know how it's supposed to work this filtering?

Update: I was referring to Xaml builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: it doesn't look possible to tag XAML builds. The below guideline is valid for vNext builds only.**

You should first assign tags to your builds before you can use filtering by tags. For example, this is the default list of builds:

[image]

Now open a certain build and assign a tag to it:

[image]

Finally, get back to the list of builds and filter by the tag you've just assigned:

[image]

Comment: This is valid only for new build system; do you know how is working for the Xaml build system?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be possible at first glance. Although "Filter by tags" UI is still there for XAML builds, I failed to find a way to assign a tag to a build...

Comment: Another indirect evidence is that TFS 2013 web UI does not have that "filter by tags" element. I have also verified the [Community TFS Build manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f), which adds missing parts to the XAML build management, and it doesn't allow to tag builds, either.